# Google charts, area chart not rendering properly what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create a graph off electricity and gas usage over the span of a year broken down into months. The graph should look something like this image but with two lines :[image]

Here is a jsfiddle of my graph: http://jsfiddle.net/79ffvayr/304/

The graph is rendering but there is no data in or months along the bottom axis. I am thinking it must be something to do with my data but I cant see what.

Here is my my javascript but I have not included the full data array as it spand every day for an entire year. See the js fiddle above for full data array

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

         ['Time', 'Electricity', 'Gas'],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',01'), 61.7, 74.04],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',02'), 91.145, 109.374],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',03'), 28.378, 74.62],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',04'), 16.75, 33.5],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',05'), 26.136, 39.204],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',06'), 466.248, 41.975],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',07'), 0, 117.414],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',08'), 42.268, 0],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',09'), 10.442, 31.326],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',10'), 56.356, 0],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',11'), 21.15, 31.725],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',12'), 55.226, 82.839],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',13'), 488.352, 610.44],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',14'), 148.252, 85.035],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',15'), 141.925, 198.695],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',16'), 102.36, 120.372],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',17'), 25.86, 30.17],
    [new Date('2017', ',01', ',18'), 127.848, 149.156],
    ]);

        var options = {
        chartArea: {

        },
                                    hAxis: {
                                        title: 'By Month',
                                        viewWindowMode: 'pretty',
                                        slantedText: false,
                                        count: -1,
                                        format: 'MMMM',
                                        gridlines: {
                                            color: 'transparent'
                                        },
                                        textStyle: {
                                            color: 'black',
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontName: 'Arial',
                                            bold: true,
                                            italic: false
                                        },
                                        titleTextStyle: {
                                            color: 'black',
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontName: 'Arial',
                                            bold: true,
                                            italic: false
                                        }
                                    },
                                    vAxis: {
                                        title: 'kWh',
                                        titleTextStyle: {
                                            color: 'black',
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontName: 'Arial',
                                            bold: true,
                                            italic: false
                                        },
                                        textStyle: {
                                            color: 'black',
                                            fontSize: 12,
                                            fontName: 'Arial',
                                            bold: true,
                                            italic: false
                                        },
                                    },

                                    legend: { position: 'top' },
                                    backgroundColor: '#fff',
                                    colors: ['#f36daa','#51b9d2'],
                                };

                                var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                                chart.draw(data, options);
                            }

     <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: I update the jsfiddle to one that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just had some extra commas in the dates...

changed --> `new Date('2017', ',01', ',01')`

to --> `new Date(2017, 0, 1)`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Electricity', 'Gas'],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 01), 61.7, 74.04],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 02), 91.145, 109.374],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 03), 28.378, 74.62],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 04), 16.75, 33.5],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 05), 26.136, 39.204],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 06), 466.248, 41.975],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 07), 0, 117.414],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 08), 42.268, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 09), 10.442, 31.326],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 10), 56.356, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 11), 21.15, 31.725],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 12), 55.226, 82.839],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 13), 488.352, 610.44],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 14), 148.252, 85.035],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 15), 141.925, 198.695],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 16), 102.36, 120.372],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 17), 25.86, 30.17],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 18), 127.848, 149.156],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 0, 31), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 31), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 3, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 4, 31), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 5, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 6, 31), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 7, 31), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 8, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 9, 31), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 10, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 01), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 02), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 03), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 04), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 05), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 06), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 07), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 08), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 09), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 10), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 11), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 12), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 13), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 14), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 15), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 16), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 17), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 18), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 19), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 20), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 21), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 22), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 23), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 24), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 25), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 26), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 27), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 28), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 29), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 30), 0, 0],
    [new Date(2017, 11, 31), 0, 0],
  ]);

  var ticks = [
    new Date(2017, 0, 15),
    new Date(2017, 1, 15),
    new Date(2017, 2, 15),
    new Date(2017, 3, 15),
    new Date(2017, 4, 15),
    new Date(2017, 5, 15),
    new Date(2017, 6, 15),
    new Date(2017, 7, 15),
    new Date(2017, 8, 15),
    new Date(2017, 9, 15),
    new Date(2017, 10, 15),
    new Date(2017, 11, 15)
  ];

  var options = {
    chartArea: {

    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'By Month',
      viewWindowMode: 'pretty',
      slantedText: false,
      count: -1,
      format: 'MMM',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontName: 'Arial',
        bold: true,
        italic: false
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontName: 'Arial',
        bold: true,
        italic: false
      },
      viewWindow: {
        //max: new Date(2017, 11, 31)
      },
      ticks: ticks
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'kWh',
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontName: 'Arial',
        bold: true,
        italic: false
      },
      textStyle: {
        color: 'black',
        fontSize: 12,
        fontName: 'Arial',
        bold: true,
        italic: false
      }
    },
    legend: { position: 'top' },
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    colors: ['#f36daa','#51b9d2'],
    curveType: 'function'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**

recommend **not using** `jsapi` to load the library, according to [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic loader (`loader.js`) from now on.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

this will also change the `load` statement to...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

Comment: Sometimes you cant see the wood for the trees. I have it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/79ffvayr/305/   but its showing January to April. How do I limit the scale to stop a December? Also to get the graph a bit smoother I guess Ill have to reduce the data points to less than every day? Or is there something I can do in the graph?

Comment: you're right about that -- once i found the commas, i stopped looking -- but just noticed another issue with the dates -- should use numbers instead of strings, and months are _zero-based_ when using that constructor -- so Jan = 0 and Dec = 11 -- as for stopping at Dec, use --> `viewWindow.max` -- changed answer above...

Comment: Or you cloud add ticks to the hAxix option.

Comment: Ticks can you expand on that?

Comment: `ticks` allow you to specify which labels to show, so long as there is enough room -- changed answer above...

Comment: That is awesome buddy, almost exactly what I am looking for. Is there anyway smooth out the data points without changing the data? I think I am  going to have to redo my query as there are to many data points to get a graph like in the picture.

Comment: Accepted, yes I have to may data points. I am going to have to group my daily totals into totals for the weeks and reduce the number of datapoints

Comment: Just on the off chance. Do you no if its possible toggle the data line to display on google charts. As in the user could hide the gas or elect line?

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35603812/5090771) for hiding a series -- you could also implement by clicking legend, rather than button, etc...